# Abbrev. (words) for "year", "month" and so on from Locale

Tags: ios, nslocale

I try to print a time period with format like this :
"2 years, 3 months, 15 days, 23 hours, 15 min and 35 sec".
I want to use these date/time abbrev (words) for another purposes too ...
Is it possible to get abbrev for "years", "months" and so on from Locale (regional), so the
output be are more friendly with different regional setings ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer ! Yes, I could add them, but I hope that exists a easy way :(

Answer (score 0):

This [NSDate+TimesAgo](https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo) category provides localized strings in times ago format e.g. a moment ago, 5 seconds ago etc as given below

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0]
NSString *ago = [date timeAgo];
NSLog(@"Output is: \"%@\"", ago);
2011-11-12 17:19:25.608 Proj[0:0] Output is: "41 years ago"
```

5
You might need to edit it to achieve your purpose. Please check license clause.